# Standard way of passing input to WebAPI for number data types?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-validation

Can someone tell about passing input for WebApi for number data types i.e int, long etc.

```
public class Emp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long Volume { get; set; }
}
```

Input set 1:

```
{
    "Id" : "1",
    "Volume" : "200"
}
```

this is working without model validation error.

Input set 2:

```
{
    "Id" : "1.2",
    "Volume" : "200.5"
}
```

Model validation failing as not able to convert values.
Error : `{"Error converting value \"200.5\" to type 'System.Int64'. Path 'Volume', line 2, position 14."}`

Input set 3:

```
{
    "Id" : 1.2,
    "Volume" : 200.5
}
```

It not gives any model validation failure, but the values mapped to C# object is Id = 1, Volume = 200.

But here also, I want model validation error as I'm passing decimal input. It should allow only whole numbers.

So what is the right pattern to send api input?

What is the right way to get model validation error when passing decimal point values to int and long data type.

```
Using int & long will make those values rounded to nearest integer value
```

How to override this to give model validation errors?

Comment: Since the value has decimal part, you should use either `double` or `decimal` data type for both `Id` & `Volume` properties. Using `int` & `long` will make those values rounded to nearest integer value.

Comment: You are trying to send *decimal* values when an *integer* is expected. You need to fix whatever code calls the API so it doesn't send decimals when integers are expected. Or change the API to accept decimals.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto , Using int & long will make those values rounded to nearest integer value - Agree. But when I pass decimal values with double quote it gives model validation error. I want same happening when passing  input set 3. As I only have to allow integer values not decimal points\

Comment: So your question is specifically how to take an integer as a parameter, and fail validation if it's not actually an integer?  (Strings already fail validation, as you know)

Comment: Are you getting model validation error like "*cannot convert string to ...*"? The current JSON parser may automatically recognize integer value enclosed inside quotes, but not decimal values.

Comment: Input set3 should give an error. Passing number as numbers, but json is tolerable so int can be sent as integer. Excepting decimals like 12.45 set model property to decimals, etc.

Comment: Updated the question, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JsonConverter attribute on properties to define a custom json converter for it.

```
public class Emp
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MyCustomIntConverter))
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public long Volume { get; set; }
}

public class MyCustomIntConverter : JsonConverter<int>
{
    //implement here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to archive what you want, but isn't a easy way.

@Saif answer is pointing to the right way.

You must change you model to avoid unwanted framework behaviors and get the raw values, for example, change the type to double or string.

Then you have to validade the arguments for yourself inside your method. If some argument is not right, you must create a model validation errro.

In mvc core, you can create a model validation error like this (in mvc should be something similar):

```
ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(emp.Volume), $"Error converting value {emp.Volume} to long");
```